# How to display back button on pdf file in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, wkwebview, pdfkit

I tried to display back button on the pdf viewController but it is not working properly.

This is the button. using this button will open the pdf

```
 @IBAction func claim_btnActn(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClaimProcedure") as! ClaimProcedure
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

This is the view using this view will display my pdf

```
import Foundation
import WebKit
import PDFKit

class ClaimProcedure : UIViewController{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    let claimPdf = "claim_process"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
//        self.displayPdf()
        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.frame)
                
                title = "Your_title_here"
                
                if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: claimPdf, withExtension: "pdf"),
                    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
                    pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                    pdfView.autoScales = true
                    pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
                    pdfView.document = pdfDocument
                    view.addSubview(pdfView)
                    pdfView.goBack(navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true))
                }
    }

    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

I tried above code.. In that I called pdf with using bundle.main.url. I want to display pdf after click button and when will pdf display on that view I want to display there back button to come back to button view.

Comment: Why add a button? If you are pushing `ClaimProcedure` onto a navigation controller then the navigation bar will have a back button. Showing a PDF is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: still it is not showing back button created by navigation controller that's the reason i have to put there button.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing how the navigation controller is setup and show how you push `ClaimProcedure`.

Comment: I updated my code ! please check once..